# Characterizations of uniformly learnable function classes in the distribution-specific setting

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension, pac-learning

Let $X$ be some input domain (a measurable space). Then let $D$ be some class of probability distributions on $X\times\{0,1\}$. We will call such distributions *learning tasks*. We say that $D$ is uniformly learnable if there exists a learning procedure $L$ mapping finite subsets of $X\times\{0,1\}$ onto functions $X\to\{0,1\}$ such that for any $\epsilon,\delta$, the test error of $L$ is at most $\epsilon$ with probability at least $1-\delta$ over random training sets of size $n$, for sufficiently large $n$.

This is just the standard setting of PAC learnability.

Let $F$ be some class of binary functions on $X$. For any $f\in F$ and any probability measure on $\mu$, we can construct a learning task by sampling from $X$ using $\mu$ and then labelling that input using $f$. Denote this distribution by $f(\mu)$. Now let $D$ denote the class of learning problems of all $f(\mu)$ for all probability measures $\mu$ and all $f\in F$. Then $D$ is uniformly learnable if and only if $F$ is of finite VC dimension (Shalev-Shwartz/Ben-David, Theorem 6.7). This is sometimes called the *distribution-free* setting.

In the *fixed-distribution* setting, $D$ is instead the set of all measures $f(\mu)$ for $f\in F$ and $\mu$ a *specific* probability measure. **When is $D$ uniformly learnable?**

I suspect this is related to Rademacher complexity, but I can't find any clear statement in any source of an if-and-only-if condition for uniform learnability.

Answer (score 0):

This question is resolved completely in [Learnability with respect to fixed distributions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759190026X), Benedek & Itai 1988.

$D$ is uniformly learnable if and only if $F$ is [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space) in the sense of the $L_1$ metric.

The non-uniform case is covered in a second paper by the same authors, [Nonuniform learning](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Nonuniform-Learnability-Benedek-Itai/fe9c43c67cd2bac32aeb0a7e9f44e5f2a5b444a6). The condition then is that $F$ be *countably* bounded, meaning for any $\epsilon$ it is covered by a countable collection of $\epsilon$-balls.